# Full Media URL in Strapi

Tags: strapi

The Strapi API responds the media URLs as something like "url:'/uploads/thumbnail.png'".
I would like to get the complete URL that links to my file as value for "url". For example: "url:'https://example.org/uploads/thumbnail.png'"

The [documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/content-api/api-endpoints.html#get-entries) also shows the full URL as response. How can I achieve this?

Comment: One option is to override the default upload function to store the full path in the database instead of a relative path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full URLs come from using an upload provider such as AWS-S3 or Cloudinary. The local provider doesn't support full URLs at the moment.

Comment: This is now available

Comment: @DallasClark how can we see this in action? I am using version 4.1.12 and I don't get the full url in the response for images. Is there a config I can change somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the problem. A full URL is not available in the response. They may have decided not to do this in case you migrate your data and assets between environments, and/or the URL changes.

Comment: I added an answer, hope it helps. Can elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

There are some potentials reasons why you shouldn’t store a full URL, and respond with a full URL. I won’t dive into those reasons.

I suggest creating the entire request/response, or creating a middleware component to intercept the response.

Then you can modify the original url value with the site’s URL. Looping through the results with something like:

```
const serverHost = strapi.config.get('server.host', 'defaultValueIfUndefined');
url = serverHost + url;
```

See the following docs for more details:

- https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations.html
- https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/middlewares.html#implementation

Answer (score 0):

### **Middleware provider resolving urls**

Regarding Dallas answer, this modifies all URLs in the outgoing HTML to be full URLs containing the domain.

```js
// File: resolveUrls.js

module.exports = (strapi) => {
  return {
    async initialize() {
      strapi.app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
        await next();
        
        // Check if response type is HTML
        const contentType = ctx.response.get('Content-Type');
        if (contentType && contentType.includes('text/html')) {
          const host = ctx.request.origin;
          const body = ctx.body;
          
          // Check if body is a string
          if (typeof body === 'string') {
            // Replace all relative URLs in the HTML with full URLs
            const regex = /(?<=href="|src=")(?!https?:\/\/)(?!data:)(?!mailto:)([^"]+)/g;
            ctx.body = body.replace(regex, `${host}/$1`);
          }
        }
      });
    },
  };
};
```

This middleware checks if the response type is HTML and if so, retrieves the response body and the request origin. If the response body is a string, it uses a regular expression to find all relative URLs in the HTML and replaces them with full URLs containing the domain.

To use this middleware in Strapi, you can add it to the middlewares array in config/middleware.js:

```json
  // Add the resolveUrls middleware to the list of middlewares
  resolveUrls: {
    enabled: true,
    // You can configure the middleware here, if needed
  },
```